# How to make a test application with First Data Global Gateway in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I 've one Rails application in which I want to integrate First Global Data Payment Gateway.I am newbie to the payment gateway so don't know how to configure this with my Rails App.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe using [Active Merchant](http://www.activemerchant.org/). There's some steps described to do that with first data [here](http://www.rorexperts.com/integrating-first-data-global-payment-gateway-in-rails-t1504.html) too.